# Не происходит сохранения в изменения в базе данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, datagridview

База данных создана в visual studio 2019. После добавления данных с помощью метода AddToDatabase я обновляю отображение данных на datagridview(привязки к бд нет) методом Upload. И все отображается, но в базе данных не сохраняется. Не понимаю в чем проблема, ведь я вывожу данные на datagridview из базы данных, и изменения провожу в базе данных а не в datagridview.Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        }
private async void AddToDatabase()
        {
            SqlCommand commandAdd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] (Id,animal,name)VALUES(@Id,@animal,@name)", sqlConnection);
            commandAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
            commandAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("animal", textBox2.Text);
            commandAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", textBox3.Text);
            await commandAdd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
private async void Upload()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table]", sqlConnection);
            try
            {
                sqlReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                while (await sqlReader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                    row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                    row.Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Id"]);
                    row.Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(sqlReader["animal"]);
                    row.Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(sqlReader["name"]);
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                if (sqlReader != null) sqlReader.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: В питоне, например, после запроса на изменение БД нужно коммитить их вроде sql.commit() . Мб здесь тоже есть какой нибудь метод коммита?

Comment: @icYFTL, погуглил. не нашел ничего подходящего мне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменения, которые вы делаете, сохраняются, они просто сохраняются в файле mdf в выходном каталоге, потому что у вас есть "Копировать всегда", вы переписываете файл, который содержит изменения для каждой сборки.
Переключайте Копировать всегда в "Копировать если новый" или не используйте AttachDbFilename и вместо этого вручную присоединяйте базу данных sql и храните ее в пути за пределами вашего каталога сборки проекта.

Comment: спасибо, все получилось